# In "Unique Morse Code Words" Question, I am facing issue by using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, string

**In this code for 1 testcase it is not working for 2nd testcases its working. Don't find where is the issue. Can someone help me to understand about its issue.**

> var arr1 = [".-","-...","-.-.","-..",".","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","-.","---",".--.","--.-",".-....","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--.."];
>
> var arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];
>
> var words = ["gin","zen","gig","msg"]

```
var mapping={};
for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    mapping[arr1[i]]=arr2[i];
}
const res = word => word.split('').map(c => mapping[c]).join('');
    var result = new Set(words.map(res)).size;
    console.log(result)
```

**For this input its working but for above array its not working can some one help me why?**

> var arr1 = ['z','y','x'];

> var arr2 = ['a','b','c'];

> var words = ['zzz','xz','zzz','yzx']

International Morse Code defines a standard encoding where each letter is mapped to a series of dots and dashes, as follows:

'a' maps to ".-",
'b' maps to "-...",
'c' maps to "-.-.", and so on.
For convenience, the full table for the 26 letters of the English alphabet is given below:

Given an array of strings words where each word can be written as a concatenation of the Morse code of each letter.

> For example, "cab" can be written as "-.-..--...", which is the concatenation of "-.-.", ".-", and "-...". We will call such a concatenation the transformation of a word.

Return the *number of different transformations* among all words we have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a close look at the two different examples (arrays) that you include, you'll find that the transformation/translation logic is reverted:

Example that works:

```js
var arr1 = ['z','y','x']; // <- Alphabet A
var arr2 = ['a','b','c']; // <- Alphabet B
var words = ['zzz','xz','zzz','yzx'] // <- Words in Alphabet A
```

Second case:

```js
var arr1 = [".-","-...","-.-." ... ,"--.."]; // <- Alphabet A
var arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e' ... ,'z']; // <- Alphabet B
var words = ["gin","zen","gig","msg"] // <- Words in Alphabet B
```

Since the translation order is different, you are not expected to see the first set of array work exactly as the second set of arrays.

Your code is expected to work one way or the other, so make sure to transform the operations accordingly.

The way to detect the point of failure, is to break the transformation process apart and `console.log` what's exactly happening at each state:

Bring this code:

```js
const res = word => word.split('').map(c => mapping[c]).join('');
```

To this form, and carefully inspect what's happening at each step. Looking closely at the output, you'll be able to detect the breaking point and refactor accordingly:

```js
const res = word => { 
  const wordSplit = word.split('');
  console.log({wordSplit}); // <- Check #1: OK
  const mapped = wordSplit.map(c => {
    console.log(c, mapping[c]); // <- Check #2 FAIL: Problem arises at this point
    return mapping[c] 
  });
  console.log({mapped}); // <- Check #3 FAIL
  const result = mapped.join('');
  console.log({result}); // <- Check #4 FAIL
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Thanks @Kostas Got the solution after your suggestion

```js
var arr1 = [".-","-...","-.-.","-..","-","..-.","--.","....","..",".---","-.-",".-..","--","--.","---",".--.","--.-",".-....","-","..-","...-",".--","-..-","-.--","--..","--"];

var arr2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'];

var words = ["gin","zen","gig","msg","mgr","mgr","gig","abp","apb",'bpr']

var mapping={};
for(let i=0;i<arr1.length;i++) {
    mapping[arr2[i]]=arr1[i];
}
const res = word => word.split('').map(c => mapping[c]).join('');

var result = new Set(words.map(res)).size;
console.log(result)
```